# Performance of the Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3

The Raspberry Pi 3 is quoted as having a 33% increase in clock speed over the Raspberry Pi 2. But what does this mean for real world performance? For example the Raspberry Pi 2 I have runs OpenELEC and play mkv files without a problem. So surely the Raspberry Pi 3 isn't going to offer me much in the way of noticeable gains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just a 33% overclock, its another chip in general. This time around it's a 64bit one. If you don't need a more powerful (and power hungry) pi, you don't need to upgrade. The Selling point for me is that wifi and blue-tooth are build in, this saves me from going out and buying wifi/bt dongles and hoping for the best. Other than that it should be able to power more demanding USB devices you connect to it. I for one will not be throwing away a Pi2 for a Pi3 as a set-top box like a kodi device.